# OSMANd Android Compiling for Eclipse and Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, openstreetmap, osmdroid, osmand

I am trying to build the OSMAnd for Android via Eclipse and Android Studio via this official build instructions at:
https://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/GradleCommandLineBuildEnvironment

I am getting following error message:
[image: http://appsforfree.org/apk/android-studio-osmand-build-error-message.png]

It is in regards to net.osmand:OsmAndCore_android:0.1-SNAPSHOT classes not available.

Can anyone point how to fix this?

Official URL does not provide anyone to ask for help either.

Answer (score 2):

I success to build OsmAnd in android studio.
You can follow this step to check out OsmAnd on Github:

1. In Android Studio's "Welcome to Android Studio" page, select "Check out project from Version Control" .
2. In "Clone Repository" page, clone from github's OsmAnd : https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand
3. In "Import Project from Gradle" page, select "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended) "
4. After import project, in "Project Window" should have 11 projects clone from github.
5. Download OsmAnd-resources, and rename directory  to "resources", place with OsmAnd Project directory.
6. Open Build Variant window: Build->Select Builder Variant
7. Set OsmAnd module's Build Variant with x86 or Fat. (Fat means include all cpu's library)
8. Run and execute on Genymotion. (or your android mobile phone)

[I share the process on my blogger.](http://sky4s.blogspot.tw/2015/09/android-studioosmand.html)
It's write down by chinese, but you can understand what I done by pictures also.

Good Luck!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As MarsAtomic suggestion, I list step what I did in androidstudio for reference.

Comment: @skyforceShen can you also post instructions for eclipse too?

Comment: I had try to import OsmAnd in eclipse, but failed.
Maybe due to I'm unfamiliar with eclipse....

Comment: For  beaumont_k:

I don't have enough reputation  to comment with you.  So I comment here to response you.

I use JDK 1.7 only, I had try JDK 1.8 , but building is failed.
Android SDK maybe not support JDK 1.8 .

Comment: beaumont_k: you can resolve .png and string problem follow  step 5,  cause by lack of OsmAnd-resources(or put in wrong place) . After resource ready, sync gradle and build. If you still have gradle problem, maybe you don't have right gradle version. Try re-open android studio and sync gradle again.